# Hero picture showing in all pages (languages) with the exception of one page (Dutch)

Tags: image, embeds, image-path

I have recently started working on EE (ex WordPress guy). I am using version ExpressionEngine2.10.1. I did not developed the site, I am just debugging and resolving issues. It is a multi-language site www.gripgrab.com. The site shows a big picture with caption in the subpage **Local heroes/cycling**. However, in the Dutch version the sub-page **local-heroes/cycling** is not showing the top-picture. Pls. see http://www.gripgrab.com/nl/local-heroes/cycling. I checked many times on the template manager and I can see that the picture (actually a slider with only one img) is embedded but it's not showing in the browser. I checked also with the inspector in Chrome and I saw that I am missing the <li> tag of the slider. I have attached a screenshot, pls. see line 351. Is it an embedding problem? Why all the other languages show the img with the exception of Dutch? I would really appreciate your help. [image: screen shot inspector Chrome]

Comment: My guess is that the content for each of those sections is set per-language, and there's no content set for the slider in Dutch. But without knowing how your site is setup re: languages and content, and without seeing the template code, it's impossible to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks Derek, yes, you´re right, every language has its own dedicated folder and own content (except the header and footer that are part of the same global embed folder). I cannot find the content of the dutch version of that page...should it be in channels? mmm...it is not easy when I haven't build the site...!

Comment: I guess there is no entry for the dutch page, as none of the content i see in the other languages is parsed. What are you using for the multi language? something like transcribe?
Can you find the channel the page is supposed to be coming from?